# is お死枚 a pun on 四枚?

Tags: counters, puns

So I was watching Hunter x Hunter episode 142, and at one point one of the characters is about to shoot a bunch of coins at the other, and he asks 君に渡すのは
何枚でしょう, which is correctly translated as "how many am I going to give back to you?".  After he shoots them though, he answers his own question saying 答えはお死枚, which is translated as "enough to kill you".  I've never seen a counter like 枚 be used in this way, but a part of me suspects this is a pun on 四枚, but the fact that he shoots far more than four coins leads me to believe this is false.  Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe a pun for おしまい（お終い）?

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe a pun for おしまい（お終い）? – Chocolate

It is indeed a pun but not for お四枚.

For further information, this is a kind of [[当て字]{あてじ}](http://hey%20are%20very%20ordinary%20tricks%20to%20be%20taught%20to%20dogs%20in%20Japan.) .

Among the heavy metal music circle, motorcycle gangs or even ordinary youngsters in Japan, this kind of [当て字]｛あてじ｝ are often used as a kind of fashion or materials for designs. They would represent ordinary words with similar pronunciation but usually unpleasant, creepy or grotesque kanjis like:

- **聖飢魔Ⅱ** sei-ki-ma-tsu (Ⅱ is two similar to *tsu* in Japanese) 世紀末｛せいきまつ｝ the end of the century, a Japanese heavy metal band
- **夜露死苦** yo-ro-shi-ku よろしく Nice meeting you.
- **夜露死苦尾寝骸死魔酢駄個裸** yo-ro-shi-ku-o-ne-gai-shi-ma-su-da-kora よろしくお願{ねが}いしますだコラ Hey, please remember me. Hey, please help me. Hey, please treat me well.
- **愛離我闘** a(?)-ri-ga-tou ありがとう Thank you!
- **氣魔愚隷** ki-ma-gu-re きまぐれ whim, whimsy
- **仏恥義理** butsu-chi-gi-ri ぶっちぎり off the charts, landslide, overwhelming, outright, resounding, sweeping, runaway
- **栖威邪苦** su-i-ja-ku 衰弱｛すいじゃく｝ breakdown, collapse, consumption, weakening, debility
- **愛羅武勇** ai-ra-bu-yuu アイラブユー I love you!
- **鬼流汰威無** ki-ru-ta-i-mu キルタイム kill time
- **出羅苦栖** de-ra-ku-su デラクス deluxe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think to further explain Chocolate and mackygoo's conclusions:

> 答えはお死枚

If a counter for flat-objects such as coins or paper is 枚, you'd quantify as 一枚, 二枚, 三枚, 四枚(read as よんまい!), 何枚, etc.

(お)死枚 can then be, as a quantifier, "enough for death."

That, and, お終い is a way of expressing "ending" someone.

Hence, the pun: "The answer is 'enough to kill/end you'"